# HP Proliant server ML310eGen8v2 not powering on

Tags: hp, electrical-power

HP Proliant server ML310eGen8v2 power on/standby button is blinking green for long time and when it powers itself on it doesnt post. No VGA output just noise. I have tested it with hundred of UPS devices and nothing changes.I also went to the HP support center and figured out that our guarantee just expired 2 months ago. Any ideia about How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the flowchart and probably the ILO logs.

[image]